# Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

If I run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.VERSION)

pyt = tf.python
```

I get version 1.6.0, but also the error:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow's `__init__.py` [manually removes the `python` name from the `tensorflow` module's namespace](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.6.0/tensorflow/__init__.py#L40):

```
del python
```

The contents of the `tensorflow.python` submodule should be accessed through `tensorflow` directly.

Comment: This is code I got from the internet. How do I do what they are doing? How do I access the submodule directly?                    self.state_variables = tf.python.util.nest.pack_sequence_as(
            self.initial_state,
            [tf.Variable(var, trainable=False)
             for var in tf.python.util.nest.flatten(self.initial_state)])

Comment: There should be `tf.contrib.framework.nest.pack_sequence_as`. [See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/nest/pack_sequence_as)